# com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: No image present

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions, text-extraction, text-recognition

when i call function annotate image from kotlin code , i get response with firebase Exception .
exception message is ===> "com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: No image present."
i added code like official documentation ==> https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/recognize-text
and i make sure i sent image to firebase function .
please how i can solve this problem ?

please how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you find the solution? Getting the same error.

Comment: Is the cloud vision api enabled for your project on google cloud. Can check with this link - https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/vision.googleapis.com

Comment: Also have you tried logging the incoming request in your cloud function to see if the image is present in it?
You can log the incoming data using `console.log` and check in https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue. I just updated the annotateImage function to safeSearchDetection

```
export const annotateImage = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "unauthenticated",
      "annotateImage must be called while authenticated."
    );
  }
  try {
    return await client.safeSearchDetection(data);
  } catch (e) {
    // @ts-expect-error
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", e.message, e.details);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. I did the same as the official document description. Error is in the code of **index.ts** file, of deploying to Firebase functions.

Need to convert **data** object to Json object then pass it to **client.annotateImage(obj)**

because **data** object is coming as a **String**.

location of the file:-
vision-annotate-images/functions/src/index.ts

```js
export const annotateImage = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "unauthenticated",
      "annotateImage must be called while authenticated."
    );
  }
  var obj = JSON.parse(data); // add this line
  try {
    return await client.annotateImage(obj); // update here
  } catch (e) {
    // @ts-expect-error
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", e.message, e.details);
  }
});
```